# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtimeClasspathCopy'

Tags: gradle, minecraft-forge

I get folowing error as soon as I create a minecraft forge mod project for the minecraft version 1.18.2 with java sdk 17:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtimeClasspathCopy'.
> Could not find net.minecraftforge:forge:1.18.2-40.1.25_mapped_official_1.18.2.
  Searched in the following locations:
    - file:/C:/Users/Hendrik/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.18.2-40.1.25_mapped_official_1.18.2/forge-1.18.2-40.1.25_mapped_official_1.18.2.pom
    - file:/C:/Users/Hendrik/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.18.2-40.1.25_mapped_official_1.18.2/forge-1.18.2-40.1.25_mapped_official_1.18.2.jar
  Required by:
      project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

The given documentation also doon't realy helpes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's a problem with your cache, so deleted it from

> C:\Users\Hendrik\.gradle\caches\forge_gradle

and rerun genEclipseRuns